# How to "multiply" dataframes with each other in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes in Python/pandas that look as follows:

**df1** = 
[[01/01/2001, 01/04/2004, 12/12/2007], 
[02/07/2002, NA, NA], 
[04/08/2012, 02/11/2018, NA]]

**df2** = 
[[1, 3, 2],
[2, NA, NA],
[3, 1, NA]]

I would like to create a third dataframe that looks as follows:

**df3** = 
[[01/01/2001, 01/04/2004, 01/04/2004, 01/04/2004, 12/12/2007, 12/12/2007],
[02/07/2002, 02/07/2002, NA, NA, NA, NA],
[04/08/2012, 04/08/2012, 04/08/2012, 02/11/2018, NA, NA]]

In other words, the second df gives the number of times that I want to copy the corresponding value of the first df into the third one. For lack of a better word, I called this "multiplying" in the question, even though I realize that this is probably wrong.

Does someone know of a way to efficiently do this? My approach would be to work with loops and lists for each row, but I'm guessing that there should by a much more efficient way of doing this in Python. Many thanks for your help and sorry again for probably using bad terminology here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fully `vectorized solution` cannot result from this logic, but we can take some benefit of `numpy` and `python Inbuilt` operation of `list comprehension`.

**LOGIC:**
**1.** Using `np.repeat` which `Array manipulation routines` we will use it to repeat along `dataframe df1` row, where argument of `repeats` of `np.repeat` function will be the row of `df2` object.

```
np.repeat(df1.iloc[i,:], df2_u.iloc[i,:].astype('i4'))
```

**2.** **Important** thing to look at is that `repeats` arguments should be type of `int` and we will use `astype('i4')` which is `np.int32` datatype to convert `df2` row while `list comprehension`.

```
df2_u.iloc[i,:].astype('i4')
```

**3.** And lastly how to repeat `np.nan` value form `np.nan` for that just update `df2` as `df2_u` where `NA` is filled with `0` using this operation:

```
df2_u = df2.fillna(0)
```

Generalized solution, here logic work as if we pass `list of lists` with `unequal-size` of `nested-list` will result into `DataFrame-Object` with broadcasted `row` with `fill` all undefined value `np.nan` object.

**CODE:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame([['01/01/2001', '01/04/2004', '12/12/2007'],
                    ['02/07/2002', np.nan, np.nan],
                    ['04/08/2012', '02/11/2018', np.nan]])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 3, 2], [2, np.nan, np.nan], [3, 1, np.nan]])

df1_sub = df1
df2_sub = df2.fillna(0)

df3 = pd.DataFrame([list(np.repeat(df1_sub.iloc[i,:], df2_sub.iloc[i,:].astype('i4')) )for i in range(df1_sub.shape[0])])
print(df3)
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
[['01/01/2001' '01/04/2004' '01/04/2004' '01/04/2004' '12/12/2007''12/12/2007']
 ['02/07/2002' '02/07/2002' nan nan nan nan]
 ['04/08/2012' '04/08/2012' '04/08/2012' '02/11/2018' nan nan]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this seems to get me almost to where I want to be! I'm still stuck with the output (arr). I get as output one array which seems to contain every row of my desired df3 as one object. Can you tell me how I can recast this array as a dataframe (with the necessary number of NaNs in each row such that it fills up to the maximum number of columns)?

Comment: @Benjamin here I updated the solution as `Method-1` and let me know if you have any issue their

Comment: only replace `2` with `0` will result correction

Comment: Amazing, this is what I was looking for! Thanks so much! PS: If you have a tip for rephrasing the question such that others with the same/a related issue might find it, I'd be happy to do so. Thanks again for your help!